# Case condition on a field that depends on another field from a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
Table 1 : 

A 
123
231
232
333

Table 2 :
1  | 2
123  981
231  999

OUTPUT Table: 

A
981
999
232
333
```

I want to get the output table from the 2 tables. Basically I want to write a case condition that I am not able to accomplish.

Comment: A useful answer requires an understanding of the relationship between the tables. You have suggestions to join - but that will not always work if table2 can have multiple rows for a given column1. Is there a foreign key constraint? Because it sure looks like there should be one. And what is the primary key? Beware asking questions using trivial examples.

Comment: Table 2 did have multiple rows. But my question pertained strictly to what and how I asked it. There was no foreign key as I was working on the same table. If I did mention all the constraints that were applied on the table then it would have been a very lengthy question and I feel that information would have been unnecessary. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for two values following statements are equivalent:

```
COALESCE(b.id, a.id)
```

or

```
case when t2.A is null then t1.A else t2.B end
```

or

```
ISNULL(b.id, a.id)
```

they have no difference in performance. only syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `case` expression here. You could use a `left join`, and just `coalesce` the results:

```
SELECT    COALESCE(b.id, a.id)
FROM      a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when t2.A is null then t1.A else t2.B end
from table1 t1 
left join table2  t2
on t1.A=t2.A
```